# Javascript button for todo list doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get my button for my To-do list to work for days now.. The button is not working but I can't figure out what the problem is. I don't want to use "onclick" in the html file I want to do the click event in the javascript file.

And then I have been trying to figure out how to get the To-do list to work with adding new tasks and being able to mark the task complete without removing it but it was harder than i thought.. I'd love to get some pointers! Appreciate it guys

```
var closebtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

function todolist(){
var li = document.createElement('li');
var btn = document.getElementById('my-button').onclick = function(){
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var input = document.getElementById('task').value;
var func = addEventListener('my-button');
var textnode = documentcreateTextNode(input);
li.appendChild(textnode);

if (input === ' '){
    alert("write")
} else {

    document.getElementById(list).appendChild(li);

}
document.getElementById('task').value = " "; 

var thePanTag = document.createElement("SPAN");
var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
thePanTag.className = "close";
thePanTag.appendChild(txt);
li.appendChild(thePanTag);

for (i = 0; i < closebtn.length; i++){
    closebtn[i].onclick = function(){
var Div = this.parentElement;
Div.style.display = none; 
}}}}
```

```
 <body>
    <h2>To-do list!</h2>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Write task" />
      <button id="my-button">Add task</button> 
    </div>
    <ul id="list">
      <li>kaa</li>
      <li>baa</li>
      <li>ss</li>
      <li>aa</li>
      <li>aaa</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: For now the code you posted has everything inside the `todolist()` function and it is not being called anywhere so nothing will happen. Call It then open the console and check the errors and try to handle them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the unnecessary code and be aware of using the correct onlick function.

Try this:

```js
var closebtn = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
todolist();

function todolist(){
  var li = document.createElement('li');  
  var btn = document.getElementById('my-button').onclick = function(){
      var ul = document.getElementById("list");
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var input = document.getElementById('task').value;
      if(input!=''){
         li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input));
         ul.appendChild(li);
      }

    }
}
```

```html
<h2>To-do list!</h2>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="task" placeholder="Write task" />
  <button id="my-button">Add task</button> 
</div>
<ul id="list">
  <li>kaa</li>
  <li>baa</li>
  <li>ss</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>aaa</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks my guy, appreciate it!!

Comment: If this solve your question, please accept it as answer.